# Express Entry System- Canada

Tags: canada, immigration, canadian-citizens

As per the conventional point system(CPS) given in this [link](http://www.cicnews.com/2015/01/introducing-nova-scotia-demand-express-entry-014370.html), 
Does the principal applicant need to score 67 points as per below chart(as eligibility) before creating express entry profile?

### [image]

Because without spouse IELTS score, am able to score only 66 points.

or

Is [comprehensive ranking system(CRS)](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/grid-crs.asp) is the only pointing system evaluation criteria(of total 1200 points) for Express Entry system?

Because,

Without spouse, my CRS score is "342" && CPS score is "66"(< 67).

With spouse, my CRS score is "333" && CPS score is "71"(> 67)[because of spouse's IELTS score] .

In both cases, express entry tool says: "Review of Minimum Entry Criteria:  Met"

Please help me!!!

Comment: @mkennedy any idea on this point system?

Comment: Hah! The link you gave is not an official government site. Check [this PDF](https://novascotiaimmigration.com/wp-content/uploads/Nova-Scotia-Demand-Express-Entry-Pilot-Stream-Guidelines-December-2014.pdf). The official NS website is http://www.novascotiaimmigration.com. You can claim your wife's language ability in the Adaptability section G. Congratulations!

Comment: @mkennedy how abouts an answer? ;)